# How to debug huge binary log file increases in MySQL replication setup?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.7

I'm running a single slave off a MySQL master. I'm using this version:

```
Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.13, for linux-glibc2.5 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

The problem I have is that the system will replicate quite happily for a day or so and then *something* hits it and the log files on the master grow hugely.

The `data` directory for the database is about 9.5GB in size.

When the replication problem happens, the log files can take up 175GB of disk space in a very short amount of time (filling the disk).

How do I debug what is happening? Can anyone suggest what to look for in the database operations that may cause this huge blow-out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your replication uses `ROW` as `binlog_format`. To verify, please run this on the master:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'binlog_format'
```

The result would be one of the following values: `statement`, `row`, or `mixed`. [More info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-log-formats.html).

In the case of `ROW` format, every changed row will add info to the bin log. If there are statements that affect a table of 1000000 rows, all these changes will be written to the binlog.

For example, suppose you have a huge table, with 1M rows, and you run a statement like this:

```
UPDATE big_table SET hashed_email=md5(email)
```

This statement will add 1M entries to the binlog when it is row based, while it adds only one entry to the binlog when it is statement based.

**Suggested solution:**

Enable the [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html) around the time when this this issue usually happens, and analyze all the statements to see if there are many that does update operation on huge number of rows.

Comment: Thank-you! That definitely could be something to do with it. Previously, the system worked on MySQL 5.5, which seems to have used statement-based logging by default.  I've swapped over from `ROW` to `STATEMENT` for this 5.7.13 installation and am going to monitor it closely now to see if the problem recurs (hopefully not!).

Comment: OK, the system has been holding up past where I was seeing problems before. The logging definitely showed me some issues. Thank-you for such a useful answer. :-)

Comment: @PeterK. - This should lead to re-thinking your need for huge `UPDATEs`/`DELETEs`.  Consider opening another Question to discuss how to redo such.  For example, `PARTITIONing` can eliminate deletes in a time-series.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks for that! I'm going to go through and see what we can do differently and will definitely ask once I have a sensibly formed question.